# How to horizontally centre a div using CSS Grid instead of margin: 0 auto

Tags: css

I want to horizontally centre a div on the page, I don't want its width to ever be wider than 400px, when the page is wider than 400 there will be equal space to the left and the right of the div and the div will be 400px wide, when the page is less than 400px the div will take up the full width of the screen.

I have gotten used to doing this with `margin: 0 auto` and `max-width: 400px`, but I want to know if there's a way the same can be achieved with css grid.

```css
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.maxwidth {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="maxwidth">
        I'm 400 pix wide :)
    <div/>
<div/>
```

Here you can see the attempt in grid

```css
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}

.maxwidth {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="maxwidth">
        I'm not 400px wide :(
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have expanded the question above which should clarify these questions, if there is any more doubt let me know and ill more detail

Comment: CSS doesn't use camelCase.

Comment: css in jsx does @connexo

Comment: You didn't put JSX, you put CSS. Also note that your closing tags are syntactically incorrect: `<div/>` must be `</div>`.

Comment: thanks for the pointer on the closing tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a 3 column grid on the parent.

The outside columns expand to take up any remaining side space and so margin is not required.

```css
.fullwidth {
  background: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0, 400px) 1fr;
}

.maxwidth {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-column: 2;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="maxwidth">
    I'm in the center with a max width
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Paulie, thank you so much for this, your solution is perfect

Comment: Explain the necessity for fake columns, please.

Comment: it was the `gridccolumn: 2` that made it genius

Comment: Are you sure about the HTML tho? `<div/>`

Comment: This has unlocked a lot of understanding about the CSS grid for me

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. `justify-items: center;` on the parent, which sets
2. `justify-self: center;` on the grid cells.

```css
.fullwidth {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  background: red;
}

.maxwidth {
  max-width: 400px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="maxwidth">
        I'm in the center with a max width
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this is close but you will notice the blue box is the same width as the content, and not 400px

Comment: That is what you yourself stated as a requirement with `max-width: 400px;`. If you want a **fixed** width, why would you use `max-width`?

Comment: yes it's true i do want the max-width to be 400px but when the page is wider than 400px I also expect it to be 400px

Comment: I'm confused. I still don't get what your expected behaviour is. So you want a fixed width of 400px?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do without defining any template too:

```css
.fullwidth {
  background: red;
  display: grid;
  justify-content:center;
  grid-auto-columns:min(400px,100%);
}

.maxwidth {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="maxwidth">
    I'm in the center with a max width
  </div>
</div>
```

Also like below:

```css
.fullwidth {
  background: red;
  display: grid;
  justify-items:center; /* it's "items" not "content" */
}

.maxwidth {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width:min(400px,100%); /* or width:100% max-width:400px */
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="maxwidth">
    I'm in the center with a max width
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both really good solutions, thank you, I didn't know you could do `width:min(400px,100%);`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
const fullWidth = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  display: "grid",
  gridAutoFlow: "column",
  alignContent: "center", // vertically centered
  justifyContent: "center", // horizontally centered
};

const maxWidth = {
};

export default function Header({ title }) {
  return (
    <div style={fullWidth}>
      <div style={maxWidth}>{title}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this centres the title but there is no max-width of 1280px set on the inner div

Comment: You can add the max-width if you want.

Comment: when adding max-width the inner div will only be as wide as the contents, I want the width to be 1280px when the page is wider than 1280px and 100% width when the page is less than 1280px

Comment: Why are you answering a CSS question using Javascript and JSX?

Comment: @connexo: this answer is based on the first draft of OP question...